# Finding Missing Numbers When Data Is Grouped In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I need to to write a query that will calculate the missing numbers in a sequence when the data is "grouped". The data in each group is in sequence, but each individual group would have its own sequence. The data would look something like this:

```
Id| Number|
----------- 
1 | 250   |  
1 | 270   | <260 Missing 
1 | 280   | <290 Missing 
1 | 300   |  
1 | 310   |  
2 | 110   |  
2 | 130   | <120 Missing 
2 | 140   |  
3 | 260   |  
3 | 270   |  
3 | 290   | <280 Missing 
3 | 300   |  
3 | 340   | <310, 320 & 330 Missing
```

I have found a solution based on this post from CELKO here:
http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/511668-query-find-missing-number

In essence to set up a demo run the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Sequence
(seq INT NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (seq));


INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO Sequence VALUES (10);

CREATE TABLE Tickets
(buyer CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
ticket_nbr INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (buyer, ticket_nbr));

INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('a', 2);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('a', 3);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('a', 4);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('b', 4);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('c', 1);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('c', 2);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('c', 3);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('c', 4);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('c', 5);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('d', 1);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('d', 6);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('d', 7);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('d', 9);
INSERT INTO Tickets VALUES ('e', 10);

SELECT DISTINCT T1.buyer, S1.seq
FROM Tickets AS T1, Sequence AS S1
WHERE seq <= (SELECT MAX(ticket_nbr) -- set the range
FROM Tickets AS T2
WHERE T1.buyer = T2.buyer)
AND seq NOT IN (SELECT ticket_nbr -- get missing numbers
FROM Tickets AS T3
WHERE T1.buyer = T3.buyer);
```

CELKO does mention that this is for a small number of tickets, in my example my numbers table is limited to 200 rows with a single column which is a primary key with each row an increment of 10 as that is what I am interested in. I modified CELKOs query as follows (added in min range):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.buyer, S1.seq
FROM Tickets AS T1, Sequence AS S1
WHERE seq <= (SELECT MIN(ticket_nbr) -- set the MIN range
FROM Tickets AS T2
WHERE T1.buyer = T2.buyer)
AND seq <= (SELECT MAX(ticket_nbr) -- set the MAX range
FROM Tickets AS T2
WHERE T1.buyer = T2.buyer)
AND seq NOT IN (SELECT ticket_nbr -- get missing numbers
FROM Tickets AS T3
WHERE T1.buyer = T3.buyer)
ORDER BY buyer, seq;
```

The output would be those numbers that are missing:

```
buyer   seq
a       1
b       1
b       2
b       3
e       1
e       2
e       3
e       4
e       5
e       6
e       7
e       8
e       9
```

This works exactly as I want, however, on my data set it is very slow (11 second run time at the moment - it appears to be the DISTINCT which slows things down tremendously and presumably will gt worse as the base data set grows). I have tried all manner of things to make it more efficient but sadly my ambition exceeds my knowledge. Is it possible to make the query above more efficient/faster. My only constraint is that the dataset I am making needs to be a SQL View (as it feeds a report) and will execute on SQL Azure.

Cheers

David

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: Where is the schema of Sequence?

Comment: +1 I was going to ask the same - is it always in increments of 10 or does each group have its own increment?

Comment: Hi Anthony, each group has the same increment of  10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to fill in the missing data from the table. The table would consist of `ID` and a `Number` which is incremented by 10.

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    ID      INT,
    Number  INT
)
INSERT INTO Test VALUES
(1, 250), (1, 270), (1, 280), (1, 300), (1, 310),
(2, 110), (2, 130), (2, 140), (3, 260), (3, 270),
(3, 290), (3, 300), (3, 340);
```

You could do this by using a Tally Table and doing a `CROSS JOIN` on the `Test` table:

```
;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Number)/10 FROM Test)
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) - 1) * 10
    FROM E4
),
MinMax AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Minimum = MIN(Number),
        Maximum = MAX(Number)
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY ID
),
CrossJoined AS(
    SELECT
        m.ID, 
        Number = Minimum + t.N
    FROM MinMax m
    CROSS JOIN Tally t  
    WHERE
        Minimum + t.N <= Maximum
)
SELECT * FROM CrossJoined c
ORDER BY c.ID, c.Number
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Seq
----------- --------------------
1           250
1           260
1           270
1           280
1           290
1           300
1           310
2           110
2           120
2           130
2           140
3           260
3           270
3           280
3           290
3           300
3           310
3           320
3           330
3           340
```

---

If you only want to find the missing `Number` from `Test` grouped by `ID`, just replace the final `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM CrossJoined c
ORDER BY c.ID, c.Number
```

to:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Number
FROM CrossJoined c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM Test t
    WHERE 
        t.ID = c.ID
        AND t.Number = c.Number
)
ORDER BY c.ID, c.Number
```

**RESULT**

```
ID          Number
----------- --------------------
1           260
1           290
2           120
3           280
3           310
3           320
3           330
```

Comment: Thank you wewesthemenace for posting so quickly I will try this when I get home!

Comment: Hi wewesthemenace, I have just run a quick test with the GROUP BY and this looks very promising. I was wondering instead of using a CTE for E1 would a static table offer more performance?

Comment: Hi wewesthemenace, I tested your solution and for what I asked it performed 3 times faster when run against my data set. However, once I started to plumb in various other lookups and joins performance degraded significantly and quickly making the original query faster?!?! This is more likely how I manipulated your script than a problem with the code above, thanks again!